# NSOutlineViewDataSource protocol only shows up when importing Cocoa.h instead foundation.h

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I was working on Lesson 49 of the Cocoa Programming on YouTube's apple programming channel and when I tried to make a delegate to the NSOutlineViewDataSource in my OutlineViewController.h file, Xcode did not know what I was talking about. I had NSObject as my superclass and it was importing Foundation.h like the video but it did not like the protocol. I had to change over to Cocoa.h to get it to work. Did Foundation change between Xcode 4.5 (I think that's what the video is using) and Xcode 6? I am running Xcode 6 on OSX 10.9.5

Thanks,

Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Foundation.framework` is much like its name says and is just the bare bones of the OSX and iOS frameworks. So stuff like strings, numbers, arrays, sets.

Note that Foundation isn't the same bunch of things on iOS and OSX but same principle, nuts and bolts.

To get all the widgets and shiny stuff that makes UI happen you need to import `Cocoa` on OSX or `UIKit` on iOS

Main moral of the story is don't trust tutorials too far as they are bound to be wrong at points.